# Using RSA encryption, how can i find d

Tags: rsa

I am using the euclidean algorithm when i have p = 163, q = 311 and e = 281. Here is what i have so far

```
N = p * q = 50693
Totient Symbol(n) = 162 x 310 = 50220

1.  50220 = 178(281) + 202     
2.  281 = 1 (202) + 79               
3.  202 = 2 (79) + 44
4.  79 = 1 (44) + 35
5.  44 = 1 (35) + 9
6.  35 = 3 (9) + 8
7.  9 = 1 (8) + 1
8.  8 = 8 (1) + 0
```

I then move on to back substitution

```
A.  9 = 1 (8) + 1   === 1 = 9-1(8)
B.  8 = 35 – 3(9)
C.  1 = 1(9)-1(35-3(9))  - 
D.  1 = 3(9) – 1(35) + 1(9)   add similar items
E.  1 = 4(9) -1(35)

9 = 44 – 1(35)
1 = 4 (44-1(35)) – 1(35)
1 = 4(44)-4(35)-1(35)

1 = 4(44) – 5(35)
```

Take value next to 35 (5), subtract it from totient
50220 – 5 = 50215
d = 50215

This is wrong as i used an online calc to verify . Can anyone point me in the right direction here, i think the back substituion is wrong

Answer (score 0):

There are two different ways to calculate RSA `d` values, the φ (phi / totient) method, and the λ (lambda / least common multiple) method. While the original RSA paper (and [RFC 2313](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313)) use phi, modern implementations (and [RFC 2437](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2437)) use lambda.

The totient value is easy: (p-1)(q-1) = 50220.
For lambda(p-1, q-1) we need to first compute GCD(p-1, q-1), the example uses the subtraction form of the [Euclidian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations):

```
GCD(162, 310)
GCD(162, 148)
GCD(14, 148)
GCD(14, 134)
GCD(14, 120)
GCD(14, 106)
GCD(14, 92)
GCD(14, 78)
GCD(14, 64)
GCD(14, 50)
GCD(14, 36)
GCD(14, 22)
GCD(14, 8)
GCD(6, 8)
GCD(6, 2)
GCD(4, 2)
GCD(2, 2)
GCD = 2
```

The least common multiple of (a, b) is `a * b / GCD(a, b)`. So the lambda value is the totient / GCD, or `25110`.

Now, to compute `dPhi = ModInv(e, phi)` or `dLambda = ModInv(e, lambda)` we can use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Modular_integers):

```
ModInverse(281, 50220)
  r=50220, newR=281, t=    0, newT=    1
  r=  281, newR=202, t=    1, newT= -178
  r=  202, newR= 79, t= -178, newT=  179
  r=   79, newR= 44, t=  179, newT= -536
  r=   44, newR= 35, t= -536, newT=  715
  r=   35, newR=  9, t=  715, newT=-1251
  r=    9, newR=  8, t=-1251, newT= 4468
  r=    8, newR=  1, t= 4468, newT=-5719
  r=    1, newR=  0, t=-5719, newT=50220
  Correcting the sign of t
  dPhi = 44501

ModInverse(281, 25110)
  r=25110, newR=281, t=    0, newT=    1
  r=  281, newR=101, t=    1, newT=  -89
  r=  101, newR= 79, t=  -89, newT=  179
  r=   79, newR= 22, t=  179, newT= -268 
  r=   22, newR= 13, t= -268, newT=  983
  r=   13, newR=  9, t=  983, newT=-1251
  r=    9, newR=  4, t=-1251, newT= 2234
  r=    4, newR=  1, t= 2234, newT=-5719 
  r=    1, newR=  0, t=-5719, newT=25110
  Correcting the sign of t
  dLambda = 19391
```

You seem to have done the descending step of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm correctly, but being unfamiliar with the back-propogation calculation (as opposed to the inline form) I don't see where you made a value or arithmetic error.